# Issues with ACAccountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType not calling completion block

Tags: ios, objective-c, social-framework, acaccountstore

I've been having this issue and can't find anything on it. I'm using the Social framework to build a basic Twitter application (a learning project for myself) and haven't run into any major roadblocks until just recently when the account store stopped completing my requests for account access. From all the samples I've read and gathered, when the application starts I request access to the accounts and then once granted can go from there.

The code I have to fetch the accounts is:

```
ACAccountType* accountType = [self.accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
NSLog(@"Making this call to getTwitterAccount");
[self.accountStore
 requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType
 options:nil
 completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError* error) {
    NSLog(@"Testing, this should show up");
    if (granted) {
        NSArray* accounts = [self.accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
        [self getAccountFromArray:accounts];
    }
    else {
        if (error.code == 6)
            NSLog(@"No twitter account");
        else
            NSLog(@"Access denied");
    }
}];
```

The two NSLog statements are in there for debugging purposes. I call the function that contains this code from `viewDidLoad` and the `getAccountFromArray:(NSArray*)` function simply determines if which account the user wishes to use for the application (presenting a modal view if necessary). My issue is with the completion block never being called unless I make a change to the accounts in the simulator. Immediately following a change to the accounts and the code executes and displays the modal (which for now just says a message) but for any other execution this block is never fired and the only print seen in the console is `"Making this call to getTwitterAccount"`. Previously, this worked fine for fetching a single account and I was able to get the timeline fetch working and printing but then it stopped firing for some reason and I haven't been able to make a success `SLRequest` or do any other actions based on it since.

I've Googled and found problems with using this function out there but none of those issues are with the completion block never firing.

**EDIT**

Okay so an update, been working at this and for some reason moving the call to the function that checks accounts into the views `initWithNibName:bundle:` method seemed to work, it executes reliably (albeit a tad after the app loads). The function is called twice but only executes the completion once and only when I call it from the `init` - maybe a reason for this?

Comment: I once had a similar issue due to not passing in any parameters in the `options:` field for the `requestAccessToAccountsWithType:` method. Can't imagine that's the root issue, but might be worth a look.

Comment: According to Apple's documentation the options is for Facebook which requires additional parameters - however I will goole around to see if there is anything I pass in for Twitter.