# iOS: Where to handle showing an account choice modal?

Tags: ios, objective-c, organization, social-framework

I'm writing a basic Twitter application (for teaching myself iOS/Objective-C) and I've run into a slight road bump. I asked a question related to it previously which received no answer and after solving that problem (kind of) I wedged in a secondary question that hasn't been responded to so I'm breaking it out into it's own question and removing it from the other. ([other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914977/issues-with-acaccountstore-requestaccesstoaccountswithtype-not-calling-completio))

Down to the question. I'm using the Social Framework for iOS 6 and it's possible for users to have one or more Twitter accounts registered in the system. Given this fact I would like to prompt the user who has more than one to choose an account from which a timeline can be loaded and so on. If there is only one then I will obviously just use it so I don't even need the modal there.

The question is where is the best place to do this? Right now I've got the `ACAccountStore` in the `initWithNibName:bundle:` function and it's testing/loading the modal when it's supposed to (just slowly). So I've got everything working I'm just curious where in the application lifetime is the best place to do this - perhaps the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` or elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I show a UIAlertView or UIActionSheet instead of a VC. It works better with singletons and is more iOS like. Just create a button per account and setup code to select that account.

Comment: The reason I show a VC is because it's attached to a View with a UIPickerView with the list of accounts registered on the device. It's asking you to choose which you want used for the pulling of timelines. Not sure what a UIActionSheet is, I'll look into it.